# How to display legend in Python matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting 4 curves as below. In each subplot I want a legend with labels being simply the variable name.  For example, for subplot defined by axs[0,0] , the legend should be "y1" and "y2", (naturally with respective lines colors ).
I tried the code below, but legends are not displayed.

```
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
    axs[0, 0].plot(x,One_year[['y1','y2']])
    axs[0, 1].plot(x,One_year[['z1','z2']])
    axs[0, 2].plot(x,One_year[['m1','m2']])
    axs[1, 0].plot(x,One_year[['p1','p2']])
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a `label` keyword argument while plotting and also call the `legend` method to draw the legend on the subplot

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)

axs[0, 0].plot(x,One_year[['y1','y2']], label= "y1 and y2")
axs[0, 0].legend()

axs[0, 1].plot(x,One_year[['z1','z2']], label= "z1 and z2")
axs[0, 1].legend()

# indexing was wrong here(in the posted code)
# axs is a 2x2 matrix
axs[1, 0].plot(x,One_year[['m1','m2']], label= "m1 and m2")
axs[1, 0].legend()

axs[1, 1].plot(x,One_year[['p1','p2']], label= "p1 and p2")
axs[1, 1].legend()

fig.autofmt_xdate()
# plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Edit: I tested with some random data and this worked. Are you getting any errors?